# Error in RecyclerView Adapter - error inflating image view class

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

```
09-26 16:24:55.490 15382-15382/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.recyclervieww, PID: 15382
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class ImageView
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
        at com.example.recyclervieww.RecyclerViewAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(RecyclerViewAdapter.java:36)
        at com.example.recyclervieww.RecyclerViewAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(RecyclerViewAdapter.java:19)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7069)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6233)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6116)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6112)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2303)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1627)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1587)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:665)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:4132)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3849)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4402)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16019)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5206)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1195)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16019)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5206)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:639)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:574)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16019)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5206)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:446)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16019)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5206)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:639)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:574)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16019)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5206)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1959)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1813)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1722)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16019)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5206)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:639)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:574)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16019)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5206)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2487)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2184)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1296)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6665)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:800)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:603)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:572)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:786)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:218)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5657)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.o
```

Comment: share your code and your xml file

Comment: You are probably not finding the correct ID or forgot to bind it in your class.

Answer (score 0):

In my Cases , error inflating R.Layout.RecyclerView xml .
Just Close the Project then open again and Let android studio fix it.